# Items form theme folder in WordPress is fetch as https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, themes

I have a weird problem in my website, all the images in my theme folder are fetch via https layer. And since my ssl is self-signed - the theme images are not displayed.

I have enabled ssl on admin page for security, but this problem was not there before. I tried to find solution everywhere but no avail.

mysite is [fdiengdoh.com](http://www.fdiengdoh.com)

It is supposed to have a patterned background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your images are loading correctly.  The ones loading via https are coming from this file, in which you appear to have hardcoded the https protocol.

http://www.fdiengdoh.com/wp-content/themes/bluediamond-v1_05/style-custom.css?ver=4.0

You should change those to relative urls.  For example:

```
html{ background-image: url(https://www.fdiengdoh.com/wp-content/themes/bluediamond-v1_05/images/pattern/pattern-1.png); }
```

should become:

```
html{ background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/bluediamond-v1_05/images/pattern/pattern-1.png); }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice that after all this time of searching (almost 1 month). I was still wondering how did that css changed by itself when it was perfectly ok before...